# Удалить все строки с повторяющимся значением в поле

Tags: php, mysql

В таблице несколько миллиардов записей. Структура простая, например:

```
field1  field2  field3
value1  ...     ...
value2  ...     ...
value2  ...     ...
value3  ...     ...
```

Нужно удалить все строки, значения в `field1` для которых повторяются. В примере выше результат должен стать таким:

```
field1  field2  field3
value1  ...     ...
value3  ...     ...
```

Ну и, конечно же, не убить сервер. Есть идеи, как подобное можно провернуть?

Comment: *Есть идеи, как подобное можно провернуть?* Чтобы не убить сервер, получите во временную таблицу список значений этого поля к удалению одним запросом, а потом удалите их другим запросом. В промежутке - прикиньте,  сколько записей потребуется удалить, и если это дофига, то удаляйте пакетами по несколько значений из темп-таблицы. Надеюсь, это поле проиндексировано?

Comment: @Akina, неужели, можно одним запросом получить записи по такому критерию?

Comment: Вроде бы ваш случай https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows

Comment: @nup Одним запросом можно получить записи по любому критерию и в каком угодно виде. В вашем случае вообще достаточно `select field1 group by field1 having count(1)>1`. И даже это можно join присоединить к delete и таким образом еще и удалить одним запросом. Остается вопрос с быстродействием удаления. Удалять все сразу и на это время блокировать всю таблицу может оказаться не приемлимым. И group by может оказаться слишком долгим и выгоднее будет прочитать все в клиента и там определиться

Comment: @AlexanderChernin Не совсем. Даже, я бы сказал, совсем не. По ссылке 1) MS SQL 2) одна из записей оставляется 3) даже MS Sql придётся несладко на таком массиве данных.

Comment: В итоге всё равно придётся сначала сортировать данные (или извлечь сразу ключи где количество записей больше одной), а уже после этого можно будет линейно пройтись по списку, удаляя дублирующие записи в передсмотрящем режиме (lookahead)

Comment: Если есть доступ к Юниксу, то можно запустить «| sort | uniq -c» по файлу, в который была сдамплена первая колонка.